# Flutter web loads as a white grey screen after token expired with an error {Uncaught TypeError: s.giM is not a function}

Tags: flutter, dart, web

When I push the flutter web app to the host it works fine, but after I close the web browser without logging out and letting the log in token expire when I open it I always got redirected to the home screen and the dashboard have a white screen and didn't load anything,
[image]
When I inspect it, I got this error in debugging

```
Uncaught TypeError: s.giM is not a function
at Dn.auE (main.dart.js:94928:45)
at Dn.E2 (main.dart.js:94930:12)
at Dn.ao9 (main.dart.js:94989:6)
at tear_off.<anonymous> (main.dart.js:4322:79)
at FW.E8 (main.dart.js:102945:76)
at main.dart.js:101499:10
at aPo.a (main.dart.js:5553:62)
at aPo.$2 (main.dart.js:50578:14)
at aOv.$1 (main.dart.js:50572:21)
at aLY.aK4 (main.dart.js:51269:34)
```

Can anyone help me? I have no idea what is causing this error